# Starting a script via Cronjob from a specific directory (for automated git upload)?

Tags: git, perl, shell, cron

I have a git repository and every night I want to have a cronjob which loads processed data into my git repository.

So first I call a shell script with the cronjob daily:

```
30 0 * * * sh /home/......../gitprojectfolder/cronjob.sh
```

This shell file produces mysql backup output. After the backups are produced, it converts the backups into a new document by using a Perl script.

That is how the Perl script is called (by absolute path <= this works):

```
perl /home/....../gitprojectfolder/upload_documents.pl
```

The Perl script then also starts the git upload after it has produced the new documents.

That is how the relevant lines in the Perl code looks:

```
system("git add --all");
system("git commit -am 'Upload of public documents'");
system("git push https://*******.git");
```

When I go to the directory with the git project folder on my server:

```
cd gitprojectfolder
# followed by my script
perl upload_documents.pl
```

Then the git upload is working.

If I invoke the Perl script via the cronjob:

```
perl /home/...../gitprojectfolder/upload_documents.pl
```

or if I invoke it from any other directory, then the upload does not work:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
```

So it seems that I can only use my script when I am logged into my console and start the Perl script from the gitprojectfolder. So my script needs to get invoked from there.

Does anyone know how this is possible? How can I alter any of my code so that the Perl script is invoked from this git project folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your cronjob, make the current job `cd` to the working directory first, then call the script from there.

```
30 0 * * * cd /home/......../gitprojectfolder/ && sh cronjob.sh
```

**Explanation:**

At the moment your `cronjob.sh` gets invoked by crontab in your home dir. You can check that by adding a cronjob to write the working directory in a file.

```
40 13 * * * pwd >whereami.txt
```

Of course, adjust the date and time accordingly.

Also see [this question on Linux & Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38951/25912) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This was exactly the answer i was looking for. Works perfectly as intended!

Answer (score 3):

In you perl script change the directory to your git repo directory:

```
chdir("<git repo dir>");
```